# ipinfo.io filter AS#### out?

Tags: php, regex, json, api

I am using ipinfo.io for some simple lookups, but I have one little problem with `echo $details->org;` It outputs "*AS15169 Google Inc.*", but I want only the ISP part so "*Google Inc.*".

Example code:

```
<?
function ip_details($ip) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
    $details = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}
$details = ip_details($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $details->org;
?>
```

Example output: http://ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8/org

Need some help, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the org field you can query `http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/org` which will give you the org as a string, which will save you from having to parse any JSON:

```
$org = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/org");
```

We can split the org string into the ASN and name by exploding on the first space:

```
list($asn, $name) = explode(" ", $org, 2);
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
function org_name($ip) {
    $org = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/org");
    list($asn, $name) = explode(" ", $org, 2);
    return $name;
}

echo org_name("8.8.8.8");
// => Google Inc.
echo org_name("189.154.55.170");
// => Uninet S.A. de C.V.
echo org_name("172.250.147.230");
// => Time Warner Cable Internet LLC
```

See http://ipinfo.io/developers for more details about the different endpoints, and rate limits.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find anything between word boundaries that starts with AS and has one or more digits followed by a space and then replace it with a blank string.

I'm not great with regex so someone might come in with a better solution that this. But I tested it at [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) and it worked for the few test cases I tried.

```
<?
function ip_details($ip) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
    $details = json_decode($json);
    return $details;
}
$details = ip_details($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$org = preg_replace('/\bAS\d+\s\b/i', '', $details->org);
echo $org;
?>
```